# System.UnexpectedException: Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment: Salesforce System Error: 1393463776-817 (799279837) (799279837)

Tags: apex, custom-metadata, abortjob

I have some code which updates a `Custom Metadata` setting, something like this:

```
public void clearValue() {
    Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata = createCustomMetadata();
    customMetadata.values.add(createCustomMetadataValue('namespace__Fieldname__c', ''));
    deployMetadata(customMetadata);
}
```

It works fine.

But when it's called after a scheduled job is aborted:

```
System.abortJob(jobId);
```

I am getting this error:

> System.UnexpectedException:
> Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment:
> Salesforce System Error: 1393463776-817 (799279837) (799279837)

I cannot find anything online about this.

I am able to work around it by calling `System.abortJob` from a `@future` method:

```
@future
private static void abortJobAsync(Id jobId) {
    System.abortJob(jobId);
}
```

But then I am unable to ensure all the intended actions completed successfully within the same transaction and report back the user accordingly.

1. Is this the expected behaviour?
2. Why is this happening?
3. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I got around this error by doing the `Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment` before calling `System.abortJob(jobId);` rather than the other way around as before. No need for an `@future`

Comment: Is the job ID the ID for the currently executing Apex?

Comment: Yes, the Job ID is correct. I checked this.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstand me; I mean - are you aborting the currently executing apex's scheduled job or a different job?

Comment: Ah-ha! I get understand now, apologies. No, I am not aborting a job from within it, or should it be executing at that time either.